# How to download large file with wget in google colab

Tags: python, google-drive-api, dataset, google-colaboratory, wget

I download a file with the following code and transfer it to Google Drive. When the file size was 44 GB, I was able to download the file and 80 GB of disk space (107 GB) was filled. I'm going to download a 340GB file, and unfortunately 107GB is too small for that. Is there a way I can download a 340GB file and put it in my Google Drive?

```
    from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import os
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/cityscape')

!wget --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookies.txt --post-data 'username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD&submit=Login' https://www.cityscapes-dataset.com/login/

!wget --load-cookies cookies.txt --content-disposition https://www.cityscapes-dataset.com/file-handling/?packageID=4
```

Comment: I don't think so, I'm afraid that you would have to purchase capacity expension of your google drive. I mean, you can't fill a small cup with large amounts of water, can you?

Comment: My Google Drive has enough capacity. By disk space (107 GB) I mean the Google colab disk.

Comment: Hamidreza-74(I can't @ your name):  I don't use Colab to do actual work to be honest. I looked it up, even if you paid for Colab Pro+ it would still gives you only 226GB disk space, still not enough for your 340 GB file. Mount the google drive, download the file to the drive and import from it, if your google drive has enough space.